# Insert json string to mongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, scala

I am new to Scala and MongoDB. I am writing a Scala program to read JSON string (it can be nested json string also) and insert the same to Mongo DB.

I tried below few things but its not working.

1) Tried to create an Document for the JSON string as below:

```
 var document = (DBObject) JSON.parse(jsonString)
```

but getting the error

```
"value JSON is not member of object com.mongodb.DBObject".
```

2) Also tried with `bson.Document` as below but still can get it working

```
var myDoc = (Document.parse(schemajson))
```

Can anyone help me out on this? Please let me know if my approach is correct. If not the please do let me know what all things I need to do.

adding code:

```
  val hadoopRDD = sc.textFile(data_file).foreach(line =>
  {
    data_array.clear

    line.split("\t").foreach(word => data_array += word)

    println(data_array)

    var final_json = (schemajson.format(data_array: _*))

    var document = (DBObject) JSON.parse(jsonString)
```

in above code final_json is the string having Json string like {"name": xyz, "age": 22}

Comment: @chridam : thanks for editing and making it easy for reading

Comment: What libs are you using? Why are you using `var`?

Comment: @yuvrajrajpurohit Are you using casbah or some other library?

Comment: @cchantep i have used all possible lib as below:import com.mongodb.DB
import com.mongodb.DBCollection
import com.mongodb.DBCursor
import com.mongodb.DBObject
import com.mongodb.Mongo
import com.mongodb.MongoException
//import scala.util.parsing.json._
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObjectBuilder
import org.bson.BsonDocument
import org.bson.Document
import com.mongodb.MongoClient

Comment: "All possible lib" just doesn't mean anything

Comment: @curious: No I can not use Casbah...for some reason..its not allowed

Comment: @cchantep: really sorry I thought u r asking about import statement which i provided. i used these lib: mondo-hadoop-core-1.0.3, mongo-java-driver-3.2.0 and spark lib

Comment: guys..any solution on this...waiting for resolution

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and below is the solution which worked for me.

I was simply using

```
var document = (DBObject) JSON.parse(jsonString)
```

which was causing error.

Instead we need to provide asInstanceOf[DBObject] which worked in my case

```
val dbObject: DBObject = JSON.parse(final_json_str).asInstanceOf[DBObject]
```